# which slice of a multi-slice lineplot is selected?

Tags: command, line-plot, dm-script

Given a multi-slice lineplot, one of the slices can be selected by clicking it in the legend with the mouse.  From the scripting side, there is a command to imgdsp.ImageDisplaySetSliceSelected(). But I can't find a command that lets me determine which slice is currently selected.  imgdsp.ImageDisplayGetSliceSelected() shows only 'No match' in the output window and I was not successful looking through the help under 'F1'.  I also tried ImageDisplayGetDisplayedLayers() but it returned 0 always.

How can I determine which slice is currently selected in a multi-slice lineplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact, one can have multiple slices selected in LinePlot display, not just one, just hold `CTRL` while clicking for multi-select.

The command you're looking for is:
`Boolean ImageDisplayIsSliceSelected( ImageDisplay id, ScriptObject slice_id )` 
And an example of its use is:

```c
imageDocument  doc = NewImageDocument("SliceTest")
imageDisplay disp = doc.ImageDocumentAddImageDisplay( RealImage("",4,100)=icol, "best" )
disp.LinePlotImageDisplaySetLegendShown(1)
disp.ImageDisplayAddImage(RealImage("",4,100)=icol**2/iwidth,"Second")
disp.ImageDisplayAddImage(RealImage("",4,100)=icol**3/iwidth**2,"Third")
disp.ImageDisplayAddImage(RealImage("",4,100)=icol**4/iwidth**3,"Fourth")

disp.ImageDisplaySetSliceSelected( disp.ImageDisplayGetSliceIDByIndex(2), 1 )
doc.ImageDocumentShow()
ClearResults()
Result("Current slice selection states:\n")
For( number i=0; i<disp.ImageDisplayCountSlices(); i++){
    Result("Slice #"+i+": '"+disp.ImageDisplayGetSliceLabelByIndex(i)+"'")
    object sliceID = disp.ImageDisplayGetSliceIDByIndex(i)
    Result("\t: Selected:"+disp.ImageDisplayIsSliceSelected(sliceID,""))
    Result("\n")
}
```

But I would further encourage you to look at the example scripts of the F1 help documentation here:

[image: F1 Help examples]

Comment: Thank you, the "As a matter of fact, one can have multiple slices selected in LinePlot display, not just one, just hold CTRL while clicking for multi-select" is the key and explains why the function I was looking for isn't there.